# $GL_2(R)$ action on binary cubic forms

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-rings

Suppose that $R$ is a local ring. Then $GL_2(R)$ acts on the space of binary cubic forms
$$p(x,y)=ax^3+bx^2y+cxy^2+dy^3, \quad a,b,c,d\in R,$$
by
$$g\cdot p(x,y)=p((x,y)g).$$
My question is **how to show that the action is faithful**.

I'm reading the paper by Gross and Lucianovic, *ON CUBIC RINGS AND QUATERNION RINGS*. The case when $R$ is a PID is easy, but I don't know how to proceed when $R$ is a local ring.